# Difficulty understanding sequential sql queries

Tags: sql

[image]

How am I supposed to work at this kind of query?

Here is what I tried: I figured starting from the bottom would be the right way to do it. So **Q** is just selecting the **cid** column from **CUSTOMER** and doing a set difference on **Q4** (so finding the **cid** in **CUSTOMER** that isnt in **Q4**.

**Q4** is just selecting the **cid** column from **Q3**

I'm not too sure what is going on in the **Q2** and **Q3** query but **Q1** is just taking the **cid, num, type** rows from the **TRANSACTION** table.

Is there a simpler way to understand what the final **Q** query is actually doing? (I am a beginner in SQL by the way.) Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly confused on what you are asking, can you put the select statement you are using in your question please?

If you are comparing **cid** from CUSTOMER to Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 you can always use LIKE and wild cards but may of misunderstood your question without the select statement.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not using a select statement because I dont know how to convert the relational algebra in the question to SQL

Comment: Hi @clay OK no problem, so just so I get it right, is my above idea of the relational algebra correct, you are looking the cid in customer which is not found in Q4? and if so what is the relevance of the TRANSACTION table?